# Which C# mocking framework takes best advantage of .NET 4?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, mocking, .net-4.0

I would assume that the more dynamic nature of .NET 4 would improve the possibility of mocking. (but I may be wrong)

Are there mocking frameworks that take advantage of .NET 4?
If yes, which does it best?

Conversely, are there mocking frameworks that do not even run on .NET 4?

Comment: Great question. Moq http://code.google.com/p/moq/ does a great job of using the C# 3.0 features to build a better mocking framework-it will be interesting to see what can be done in 4.0

Comment: moq is planning optional/named parameter support: http://code.google.com/p/moq/issues/detail?id=221

Comment: Problems in Rhino Mocks prompted me into looking for a question like this. (Problem: System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match found.) No fix or new version out yet, only workarounds which are not ideal. Just giving a heads up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think any framework does this now.

If I had to guess, I'd vote for Moq.  Daniel Cazzulino was [first to take advantage](http://www.clariusconsulting.net/blogs/kzu/archive/2007/12/18/LinqtoMockMoqisborn.aspx) of the new linq language features in a mocking framework.  I don't see any updates specifically mentioning the `dynamic` keyword, but I bet he's thinking about it at this very moment....